# Buscar un Nodo por el id en neo4j

Tags: php, doctrine, neo4j

estoy trabajando con neo4j, necesito hacer una consulta para recuperar un nodo por el id y no encuentra el nodo que le especifico, si filtro por otra propiedad sí lo encuentra pero si le especifico el id no encuentra. Si entro directo desde la web y escribo: `MATCH (e:Event) WHERE id(e) = 23 RETURN e`, sí retorna el nodo que deseo, pero cuando lo hago a través del repositorio de Doctrine no funciona. Este es mi código:

```
$entityManager = EntityManager::create('bolt://neo4j:1234567@neo4j:7687');
        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Event::class);
        /**@var Event $event*/
        $event = $repository->findOneBy(['id' => 23]);

        if ($event === null) {
            echo 'event not found' . PHP_EOL;
            exit(1);
        }

        echo sprintf("linkId:- %s; externalId: %s; id:%d\n", $event->getLinkId(), $event->getExternalId(), $event->getId());
```

este es la entidad Event:

```
/**
 *
 * @OGM\Node(label="Event")
 */
class Event implements ToArrayInterface
{        
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @OGM\GraphId()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     */
    protected $linkId;    

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     */
    protected $externalId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @OGM\Property(type="string")
     */
    protected $data;
```

Si en lugar de filtar por la propiedad '**id**' filtro por la propiedad **'name'**, sí devuelve el nodo, por eso es que conozco que ese nodo tiene el id=23, sin embargo, cuando filtro por el id, no encuentra el nodo, devuelve **null** y por tanto **'event not found'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Neo4j al **id** de los Nodos se le da un tratamiento diferente que al resto de las propiedades, por ejemplo, supongamos que nuestros nodos tienen como propiedades **id, nombre, propietario**, si queremos buscar los eventos que tengan como propietario a  **Pepe**, tecleamos: 
`Match (e:Event) where e.propietario = "pepe" Return e`, 
o lo que es lo mismo: 
`Match (e:Event{propietario:"pepe"}) Return e`, desde el repositorio sería:

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Event::class);
        /**@var Event $event*/
        $event = $repository->findOneBy(['propietario' => "pepe"]);
```

Sin embargo, si queremos retornar el evento que tenga como **id**, el valor **5**, no basta con cambiar la propiedad **propietario** por **id**, en ese caso la consulta sería: `Match (e:Event) where id(5)=1 Return e`, por esta razón si vamos a ejecutar desde el repositorio, no bastaría utilizar el método **findOneBy**, este es el que se utiliza para las propiedades comunes, para el **id** hay que utilizar **findOneById**:

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Event::class);
            /**@var Event $event*/
            $event = $repository->findOneById(['id' => 5]);
```